# To get user id from username in instagram api

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Any ways to get user id from username in instagram api?

Other than user/search endpoint and instagram front code cracking (https://instagram.com/{username}/?a__=1)

Answer (score 0):

You can get user id from username using instagram api.

Register your app here:https://www.instagram.com/developer and submit review for public_content permission.

Using their https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_search

api you can get information about user.

To get working above api make sure you have public_content permission approved for your app.